# Authenticate with TweetSharp using Token and TokenSecret

Tags: c#, wpf, twitter, tweetsharp

I'm using TweetSharp in a WPF app to connect to a user Twitter account and retrieve tweets. I'm doing the login using the OAuth and Pin verification, using the following code:

Showing the login page

```
TwitterService _twitterService = new TwitterService(_consumerKey, _consumerSecret);
_requestToken = _twitterService.GetRequestToken();
Uri uri = _twitterService.GetAuthorizationUri(_requestToken);
webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
```

Submitting the Pin for token and tokenSecret exchange:

```
OAuthAccessToken _access = _twitterService.GetAccessToken(_requestToken, _pin);
if(_twitterService.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
    _twitterService.AuthenticateWith(_access.Token, _access.TokenSecret);
    // Connection successful    
} else {
    // Error connecting
}
```

After this I save the `token` and `tokenSecret` in the database for future use. Next time the user enters the app he shouldn't be asked to give permissions a second time, and since I have the `consumerKey`, `consumerSecret`, `token` and `tokenSecret` I think I should be able to establish a connection without requesting for an OAuth.
So, my questions are:
How do I connect to Twitter using TweetSharp and having the `token` and `tokenSecret`?
Also, how do I verify if the tokens are valid?

Answer (score 1):

I figured how to do the authentication. I thought it was not working because the TwitterService response always came back null, but it actually retrieves the fetched data. So in short, the answer is this:

```
TwitterService _twitterService = new TwitterService();
_twitterService.AuthenticateWith(_cosKey, _cosSecret, _tkn, _tknSecret);
IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> tweets = _twitterService.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions());
// tweets count = 20
```

I still don't know how to check if the `TwitterService` is valid if incorrect `token` and `tokenSecret` are passed.